# Is it possible to set the svg width and height 100% in matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pipeline which is generating 30 individual boxplots svgs using matplotlib + seaborn. I want to visualize them in a 5*6 grid.
Since I want to be able to zoom on specific plots I thought about something like that:https://codepen.io/arminsolecki/pen/xERZZb

It works but unfortunately the svg does not fit in the iframe.

I learned from another stackoverflow question 
[Why don't my SVG images scale using the CSS "width" property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056537/why-dont-my-svg-images-scale-using-the-css-width-property)

that I have to modify the following line in the svg.

```
<svg height="720pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 720 720" width="720pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

I know I can do it using a xml parser but I am wondering if there is no better way? Like setting width/height to 100% when doing plt.savefig?

Comment: Matplotlib does not provide any interface for that, so yes, you will want to parse the svg and change the attributes according to your needs.