# 3000x3000px img with 100% width on mobile Safari/iOS says img height is 3000px still

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

If I inspect the `img` in Safari Mobile / iOS using the debug dev tools, it shows a very tall and slender rectangle that is 320px-ish wide (width of iPhone) but 3000px tall. The image isn't stretched however, it's aspect ratio *visibly* is maintained, so it looks right. But what is wrong is that the image is 3000px in height. It should be 320px in height (for square image in this case). What am I missing here?

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  position: static;
}

section {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  padding: 64px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <img src="myimg.svg" width='100%'>
  </section>
</body>
```

I am also rotating the image in CSS, if that makes a difference, using `transform: rotate(...)` in an `animation`.

Comment: is it shown well in chrome ?

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056537/why-dont-my-svg-images-scale-using-the-css-width-property

Comment: It could be that Safari has problems keeping the proportions in a flex item. If you remove `display:flex`, does it work as desired then? (This won't be a solution, but at least it'll help pinpointing the problem.)

Comment: you should add  img{max-width:100%;height:auto;}

Answer (score 0):

You must specify `height: auto` for the `img` to ensure scaling to width because the image's original height will be applied.

```
<img src="myimg.svg" width='100%' style="height: auto;">
```