# Styling SVG as a React Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, create-react-app

Following the create-react-app doc, I [imported a svg as a react component](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs).

However, I can't seem to resize or position it properly, whether it's inline or through css.

I want to scale the SVG component to the same size as my other icon of 100px by 100px, then position at the bottom center of the screen.

I tried setting a width and height props for the svg component.

```js
<IconClose
  className="bubbleBin"
  alt="close bubble"
  height="100px"
  width="100px"
  // viewBox="0 0 100 100"
/>
```

and in css.

```js
.bubbleBin {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Here's the minimal code to reproduce it. Full code in [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-styling-svg-component-pe2cg?fontsize=14) if needed.

```js
...
import { ReactComponent as IconClose } from './assets/icon_close.svg';

function App() {
  const ICON_WIDTH = 100;
  const ICON_HEIGHT = 100;

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
       <img
         src={require('./assets/cat_icon.png')}
         width={String(ICON_WIDTH)}
         height={String(ICON_HEIGHT)}
         alt="cat icon"
         draggable={false}
       />
      <IconClose
        className="bubbleBin"
        alt="close bubble"
        height="100px"
        width="100px"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I expect the svg to be the same size as my cat icon but this is the result instead. [image: svg styling problem in react]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with React. SVG image has a predefined `width` and `height` from the `viewBox`, and will not scale with the `width`/`height` properties as a result. You can read more about how SVG images work [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag).

Your two options are to use `transform: scale(X)` on the image which is a bit of a hack, or you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056537/why-dont-my-svg-images-scale-using-the-css-width-property) to see how to properly change the SVG image `viewBox`. This is a much better option than transforming the image, but I provided both examples to give an understanding of why you're having an issue with `width`/`height`.

Answer (score 2):

The `viewBox` of your SVG just has extra space around it. I quickly eyeballed a new viewbox for you. Try this:

```
<IconClose
  className="bubbleBin"
  alt="close bubble"
  height="100px"
  width="100px"
  viewBox="9 9 26 26"
/>
```

Here is a forked project with the change.

https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-styling-svg-component-8wwtw

These values seem to work nicely, you may be able to tweak them a bit more, if you need to use decimal values that's generally fine (`9.5` for example).

Comment: It's the same size now but I have trouble understanding how you came up with those viewBox numbers. MDN states that their attributes are min-x, min-y, width and height.