# Why is one of my icons smaller when the rest are the correct size?

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS to set all of the icons to be 30x30 pixels, and the Telegram icon is the only one that is the wrong size. The HTML source has the SVGs included.

```css
.icon {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.share-buttons {
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 25px 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.share-buttons a {
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.share-buttons svg {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="share-buttons">
  <a class="twitter-share" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1313%2fblog%2fblog-post-newsletter%2f&amp;text=Newsletter%20for%20my%20blog%20posts&amp;via=bbaovanc"><svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-2 -4 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M20 1.907a8.292 8.292 0 0 1-2.356.637A4.07 4.07 0 0 0 19.448.31a8.349 8.349 0 0 1-2.607.98A4.12 4.12 0 0 0 13.846.015c-2.266 0-4.103 1.81-4.103 4.04 0 .316.036.625.106.92A11.708 11.708 0 0 1 1.393.754a3.964 3.964 0 0 0-.554 2.03 4.02 4.02 0 0 0 1.824 3.363A4.151 4.151 0 0 1 .805 5.64v.05c0 1.958 1.415 3.591 3.29 3.963a4.216 4.216 0 0 1-1.08.141c-.265 0-.522-.025-.773-.075a4.098 4.098 0 0 0 3.832 2.807 8.312 8.312 0 0 1-5.095 1.727c-.332 0-.658-.02-.979-.056a11.727 11.727 0 0 0 6.289 1.818c7.547 0 11.673-6.157 11.673-11.496l-.014-.523A8.126 8.126 0 0 0 20 1.907z"></path><title>twitter icon</title></svg></a>

  <a class="facebook-share" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1313%2fblog%2fblog-post-newsletter%2f"><svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-7 -2 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M2.046 3.865v2.748H.032v3.36h2.014v9.986H6.18V9.974h2.775s.26-1.611.386-3.373H6.197V4.303c0-.343.45-.805.896-.805h2.254V0H6.283c-4.34 0-4.237 3.363-4.237 3.865z"></path><title>facebook icon</title></svg></a>

  <a class="linkedin-share" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1313%2fblog%2fblog-post-newsletter%2f"><svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-2 -2 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M19.959 11.719v7.379h-4.278v-6.885c0-1.73-.619-2.91-2.167-2.91-1.182 0-1.886.796-2.195 1.565-.113.275-.142.658-.142 1.043v7.187h-4.28s.058-11.66 0-12.869h4.28v1.824l-.028.042h.028v-.042c.568-.875 1.583-2.126 3.856-2.126 2.815 0 4.926 1.84 4.926 5.792zM2.421.026C.958.026 0 .986 0 2.249c0 1.235.93 2.224 2.365 2.224h.028c1.493 0 2.42-.989 2.42-2.224C4.787.986 3.887.026 2.422.026zM.254 19.098h4.278V6.229H.254v12.869z"></path><title>linkedin icon</title></svg></a>

  <a class="reddit-share" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://reddit.com/submit?url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1313%2fblog%2fblog-post-newsletter%2f&amp;title=Newsletter%20for%20my%20blog%20posts"><svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-2 -3 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M19.986 8.029a2.51 2.51 0 0 0-4.285-1.771c-1.404-.906-3.197-1.483-5.166-1.573a2.734 2.734 0 0 1 1.028-2.139 2.735 2.735 0 0 1 2.315-.539l.112.025c0 .028-.004.056-.004.084a2.095 2.095 0 1 0 .328-1.121L14.113.95a3.812 3.812 0 0 0-3.228.752 3.812 3.812 0 0 0-1.433 2.983c-1.97.09-3.762.667-5.165 1.572a2.51 2.51 0 1 0-2.94 3.994c-.061.31-.093.628-.093.952 0 3.606 3.912 6.53 8.74 6.53 4.826 0 8.739-2.924 8.739-6.53 0-.324-.032-.641-.093-.952a2.508 2.508 0 0 0 1.346-2.222zm-3.905-6.925a1.013 1.013 0 0 1 0 2.025 1.013 1.013 0 0 1 0-2.025zM1.083 8.03c0-.787.64-1.427 1.427-1.427.337 0 .646.118.89.314-.763.655-1.354 1.425-1.721 2.27a1.423 1.423 0 0 1-.596-1.157zm14.442 6.923c-1.465 1.095-3.43 1.698-5.532 1.698s-4.067-.603-5.531-1.698c-1.37-1.023-2.125-2.355-2.125-3.75 0-1.394.754-2.725 2.125-3.75C5.926 6.359 7.89 5.757 9.993 5.757c2.103 0 4.067.602 5.532 1.697 1.37 1.024 2.125 2.355 2.125 3.75 0 1.394-.755 2.726-2.125 3.75zm2.782-5.767c-.367-.845-.958-1.614-1.721-2.269.244-.196.554-.314.89-.314.787 0 1.427.64 1.427 1.427 0 .476-.235.898-.596 1.156z"></path><circle cx="6.801" cy="9.678" r="1.143"></circle><circle cx="13.185" cy="9.678" r="1.143"></circle><path d="M12.701 12.455a4.357 4.357 0 0 1-2.94 1.138 4.325 4.325 0 0 1-3.195-1.39.541.541 0 1 0-.793.738 5.47 5.47 0 0 0 3.988 1.735 5.437 5.437 0 0 0 3.67-1.421.541.541 0 1 0-.73-.8z"></path><title>reddit icon</title></svg></a>

  <a class="telegram-share" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://t.me/share/url?url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1313%2fblog%2fblog-post-newsletter%2f&amp;text=Newsletter%20for%20my%20blog%20posts"><svg class="icon" width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor"><path d="M10 0c5.523 0 10 4.477 10 10s-4.477 10-10 10S0 15.523 0 10 4.477 0 10 0Zm4.442 6c-.381.007-.966.207-3.779 1.362a485.41 485.41 0 0 0-5.907 2.512c-.48.189-.73.373-.753.553-.044.346.46.453 1.094.657.517.166 1.213.36 1.575.368.328.007.694-.127 1.098-.4 2.76-1.84 4.183-2.769 4.273-2.789.063-.014.15-.032.21.02.059.052.053.15.046.177-.05.211-2.641 2.538-2.79 2.691l-.072.072c-.55.543-1.105.898-.147 1.521.866.563 1.37.922 2.26 1.5.57.368 1.017.805 1.605.752.271-.025.55-.276.693-1.026.335-1.77.995-5.608 1.147-7.19a1.742 1.742 0 0 0-.017-.393.42.42 0 0 0-.144-.27c-.121-.098-.309-.118-.392-.117Z"></path><title>telegram icon</title></svg></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It appears to be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056537/why-don-t-svg-images-scale-using-the-css-width-property , It has something to do with the way that final SVG was defined when it was created.

Comment: Just checked and out of those icons, the LinkedIn one (the one that's wrongly sized) is the only one that doesn't have the `viewBox` parameter set. Now I just need to figure out what to do to fix this. Removing the `width` and `height` fields didn't help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your svg telegram is not the same width and height and viewbox. Let me know if this is good.

```css
.icon {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
}

.share-buttons {
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 25px 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.share-buttons a {
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.share-buttons svg {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.telegram-share > svg {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  margin: 10px -7px -7px 10px
  }
```

```html
<div class="share-buttons">
  <a class="twitter-share" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1313%2fblog%2fblog-post-newsletter%2f&amp;text=Newsletter%20for%20my%20blog%20posts&amp;via=bbaovanc"><svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-2 -4 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M20 1.907a8.292 8.292 0 0 1-2.356.637A4.07 4.07 0 0 0 19.448.31a8.349 8.349 0 0 1-2.607.98A4.12 4.12 0 0 0 13.846.015c-2.266 0-4.103 1.81-4.103 4.04 0 .316.036.625.106.92A11.708 11.708 0 0 1 1.393.754a3.964 3.964 0 0 0-.554 2.03 4.02 4.02 0 0 0 1.824 3.363A4.151 4.151 0 0 1 .805 5.64v.05c0 1.958 1.415 3.591 3.29 3.963a4.216 4.216 0 0 1-1.08.141c-.265 0-.522-.025-.773-.075a4.098 4.098 0 0 0 3.832 2.807 8.312 8.312 0 0 1-5.095 1.727c-.332 0-.658-.02-.979-.056a11.727 11.727 0 0 0 6.289 1.818c7.547 0 11.673-6.157 11.673-11.496l-.014-.523A8.126 8.126 0 0 0 20 1.907z"></path><title>twitter icon</title></svg></a>

  <a class="facebook-share" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1313%2fblog%2fblog-post-newsletter%2f"><svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-7 -2 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M2.046 3.865v2.748H.032v3.36h2.014v9.986H6.18V9.974h2.775s.26-1.611.386-3.373H6.197V4.303c0-.343.45-.805.896-.805h2.254V0H6.283c-4.34 0-4.237 3.363-4.237 3.865z"></path><title>facebook icon</title></svg></a>

  <a class="linkedin-share" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1313%2fblog%2fblog-post-newsletter%2f"><svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-2 -2 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M19.959 11.719v7.379h-4.278v-6.885c0-1.73-.619-2.91-2.167-2.91-1.182 0-1.886.796-2.195 1.565-.113.275-.142.658-.142 1.043v7.187h-4.28s.058-11.66 0-12.869h4.28v1.824l-.028.042h.028v-.042c.568-.875 1.583-2.126 3.856-2.126 2.815 0 4.926 1.84 4.926 5.792zM2.421.026C.958.026 0 .986 0 2.249c0 1.235.93 2.224 2.365 2.224h.028c1.493 0 2.42-.989 2.42-2.224C4.787.986 3.887.026 2.422.026zM.254 19.098h4.278V6.229H.254v12.869z"></path><title>linkedin icon</title></svg></a>

  <a class="reddit-share" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://reddit.com/submit?url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1313%2fblog%2fblog-post-newsletter%2f&amp;title=Newsletter%20for%20my%20blog%20posts"><svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-2 -3 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor"><path d="M19.986 8.029a2.51 2.51 0 0 0-4.285-1.771c-1.404-.906-3.197-1.483-5.166-1.573a2.734 2.734 0 0 1 1.028-2.139 2.735 2.735 0 0 1 2.315-.539l.112.025c0 .028-.004.056-.004.084a2.095 2.095 0 1 0 .328-1.121L14.113.95a3.812 3.812 0 0 0-3.228.752 3.812 3.812 0 0 0-1.433 2.983c-1.97.09-3.762.667-5.165 1.572a2.51 2.51 0 1 0-2.94 3.994c-.061.31-.093.628-.093.952 0 3.606 3.912 6.53 8.74 6.53 4.826 0 8.739-2.924 8.739-6.53 0-.324-.032-.641-.093-.952a2.508 2.508 0 0 0 1.346-2.222zm-3.905-6.925a1.013 1.013 0 0 1 0 2.025 1.013 1.013 0 0 1 0-2.025zM1.083 8.03c0-.787.64-1.427 1.427-1.427.337 0 .646.118.89.314-.763.655-1.354 1.425-1.721 2.27a1.423 1.423 0 0 1-.596-1.157zm14.442 6.923c-1.465 1.095-3.43 1.698-5.532 1.698s-4.067-.603-5.531-1.698c-1.37-1.023-2.125-2.355-2.125-3.75 0-1.394.754-2.725 2.125-3.75C5.926 6.359 7.89 5.757 9.993 5.757c2.103 0 4.067.602 5.532 1.697 1.37 1.024 2.125 2.355 2.125 3.75 0 1.394-.755 2.726-2.125 3.75zm2.782-5.767c-.367-.845-.958-1.614-1.721-2.269.244-.196.554-.314.89-.314.787 0 1.427.64 1.427 1.427 0 .476-.235.898-.596 1.156z"></path><circle cx="6.801" cy="9.678" r="1.143"></circle><circle cx="13.185" cy="9.678" r="1.143"></circle><path d="M12.701 12.455a4.357 4.357 0 0 1-2.94 1.138 4.325 4.325 0 0 1-3.195-1.39.541.541 0 1 0-.793.738 5.47 5.47 0 0 0 3.988 1.735 5.437 5.437 0 0 0 3.67-1.421.541.541 0 1 0-.73-.8z"></path><title>reddit icon</title></svg></a>

  <a class="telegram-share" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://t.me/share/url?url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1313%2fblog%2fblog-post-newsletter%2f&amp;text=Newsletter%20for%20my%20blog%20posts"><svg class="icon" width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor"><path d="M10 0c5.523 0 10 4.477 10 10s-4.477 10-10 10S0 15.523 0 10 4.477 0 10 0Zm4.442 6c-.381.007-.966.207-3.779 1.362a485.41 485.41 0 0 0-5.907 2.512c-.48.189-.73.373-.753.553-.044.346.46.453 1.094.657.517.166 1.213.36 1.575.368.328.007.694-.127 1.098-.4 2.76-1.84 4.183-2.769 4.273-2.789.063-.014.15-.032.21.02.059.052.053.15.046.177-.05.211-2.641 2.538-2.79 2.691l-.072.072c-.55.543-1.105.898-.147 1.521.866.563 1.37.922 2.26 1.5.57.368 1.017.805 1.605.752.271-.025.55-.276.693-1.026.335-1.77.995-5.608 1.147-7.19a1.742 1.742 0 0 0-.017-.393.42.42 0 0 0-.144-.27c-.121-.098-.309-.118-.392-.117Z"></path><title>telegram icon</title></svg></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the width and height in the svg didn't have any effect because the issue still persisted even when removing those parameters. Adding what you put for viewBox does help, however I would like to try to do it without modifying the svg source if possible. If not I can try to make a pull request to the source I'm getting the icons from.

Comment: let me try one other solution i'm thinking and ill edit my answer for you if it works.

Comment: @bbaovanc Look at the edited version, this is some other way I can think of. Let me know if this will works for you. Or else I'll reverse it to the original one or think of other way

Comment: I guess this will have to work for now, although I modified the margin a bit to try and get it more centered. Now I have `margin: 9px -9px -9px 9px;`.

Comment: cool yeah this is other way you can really modify it. or best way is directly to the svg. Happy coding :)